# Angular app in production slow to load with 9 second load time and huge file size

Tags: javascript, angular

The website works efficiently and very quickly on the local, but as soon as I uploaded my application to Heroku, I was shocked at how slow the launch was for the first time, and after that it got somewhat better .. I noticed that the vendor.js file reached 3 mb and the website takes arround 10 second for the first time loading

I tried to update package.json

```
       "build:prod": "ng build --prod --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path --buildOptimizer"



     "buildOptimizer": true,
```

Comment: what do you mean with "on the local" you run the build script on local environment and work with this?

Comment: You have specified `--vendor-chunk` option which means that Webpack will bundle "all" of `node_modules` in single file.
These options that you specify are meant for use when you really know what you are doing and for specific cases, I would suggest for you to remove them and use default build, it is optimized for most use cases

Comment: on localhost not on production but if I ran ng build --prod on localhost (on my laptop) it works fast but online very slow